# Hashtable or Binary Tree to search/insert/print/delete hashtags in a given text?

Tags: binary-tree, hashtable

I have some doubts about, what is the best data structure for this task.
I have multiple texts with #hashtags, and I want to detect and insert hashtags of that text in a good data structure.

**small example:**

```
hey #my #name is blah #my name blah blah
```

then i Have

```
#my #name #my

#my 2
#name 1
```

I'm thinking about using a hashtable, so i can insert and lookup an hashtag with O(1). The problem is. If i want to print all the hashtags sorted by hashtag repetitions (and then alphabetically to break ties) I have to do it with O(N log N). Also if I want to find the hashtag with max repetitions I have to do it with O(N).

On the other hand, I have a Binary tree. I get insertion and lookup with O(log N) which is worst then HashTable, but I get O(N) printing in order, and O(log N) findind the max (O(1) with Binary Heap?) .

Which data structure give me the fastest solution? Binary Tree becuse give me a better average complexity? Binary Heap? There is any better Data Structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I get O(N) printing in order, and O(log N) findind the max (O(1) with Binary Heap?)

If you use a binary tree as your main data structure while counting repetitions of the hashtags, you'll need to have it sorted alphabetically by the word in question, so that won't help you print "sorted by hashtag repetitions".  And, you can trivially calculate the max while populating a hash table - there's no need to do another operation post insertions.

**Solution**: have a hash map from hashtag to count.  Each time you increment a repetition count, if it's then greater than any you've seen before, remember that max_count value.

Then create an array of max_count (+1 if your language uses 0-based indexing) variable-sized arrays, and iterate the hash table appending the hashtags into the array index matching their frequency count.  Then to print your results, iterate the outer frequency array, sorting the variable-length array of hashtags at each index then printing them.